# Converting RMarkdown to LaTeX without additional packages

Tags: pandoc, markdown

I'm wanting to convert a [markdown document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rqg4chfb4xtnq4j/msim-eg.md) into LaTeX for inclusion in my thesis. Unfortunately, the output of my command,

```
pandoc -f markdown -t latex --standalone  msim-eg.md > msimeg.tex
```

results in output that requires a large number of preamble items that I do not want in my final document:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\else
  \ifluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \fi
\fi
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineShortVerb[commandchars=\\\{\}]{\|}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
% Add ',fontsize=\small' for more characters per line
\newenvironment{Shaded}{}{}
\newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\DataTypeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.13,0.00}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\BaseNTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\FloatTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textit{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\OtherTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\AlertTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\FunctionTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.02,0.16,0.49}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\RegionMarkerTok}[1]{{#1}}
\newcommand{\ErrorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% We will generate all images so they have a width \maxwidth. This means
% that they will get their normal width if they fit onto the page, but
% are scaled down if they would overflow the margins.
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth
\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\makeatother
\let\Oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\Oldincludegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{#1}}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage[setpagesize=false, % page size defined by xetex
              unicode=false, % unicode breaks when used with xetex
              xetex,
              colorlinks=true,
              linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[unicode=true,
              colorlinks=true,
              linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true, pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

How can I get pandoc to export without needing all these preamble items?
(Without the standalone flag the output is the same and clearly requires a big preamble. E.g:

```
\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\CommentTok{# Read in the data in long form (normaly read.table() used)}
\NormalTok{c.names <- }\KeywordTok{c}\NormalTok{(}\StringTok{"id"}\NormalTok{, }\StringTok{"age"}\NormalTok{, }\StringTok{"sex"}\NormalTok{)}
\NormalTok{USd <- }\KeywordTok{c}\NormalTok{(}\DecValTok{1}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{59}\NormalTok{, }\StringTok{"m"}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{2}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{54}\NormalTok{, }\StringTok{"m"}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{3}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{35}\NormalTok{, }\StringTok{"m"}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{4}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{73}\NormalTok{, }\StringTok{"f"}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{5}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{49}\NormalTok{, }\StringTok{"f"}\NormalTok{)}
\NormalTok{USd <- }\KeywordTok{matrix}\NormalTok{(USd, }\DataTypeTok{nrow =} \DecValTok{5}\NormalTok{, }\DataTypeTok{byrow =} \NormalTok{T)  }\CommentTok{# Convert long data into matrix, by row}
\NormalTok{USd <- }\KeywordTok{data.frame}\NormalTok{(USd)  }\CommentTok{# Convert this into a dataframe}
\KeywordTok{names}\NormalTok{(USd) <- c.names  }\CommentTok{# Add correct column names}
\NormalTok{USd$age <- }\KeywordTok{as.numeric}\NormalTok{(}\KeywordTok{levels}\NormalTok{(USd$age)[USd$age])  }\CommentTok{# Age is a numeric variable}

\NormalTok{USd  }\CommentTok{# Show the data frame in R}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}
\begin{verbatim}
##   id age sex
## 1  1  59   m
## 2  2  54   m
## 3  3  35   m
## 4  4  73   f
## 5  5  49   f
\end{verbatim}
\subsubsection{Geographical data}

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\CommentTok{# Read in the data in long form (normaly read.table() used)}
\NormalTok{category.labels <- }\KeywordTok{c}\NormalTok{(}\StringTok{"16-49"}\NormalTok{, }\StringTok{"50+"} \CommentTok{# Age constraint }
             \NormalTok{,}\StringTok{"m"}\NormalTok{, }\StringTok{"f"} \CommentTok{# Sex constraint}
             \CommentTok{#,"bicycle", "bus", "car.d", "car.p", "walk" # Mode constraint}
             \NormalTok{)}
\NormalTok{all.msim <- }\KeywordTok{c}\NormalTok{(  }\DecValTok{8}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{4}\NormalTok{,    }\DecValTok{6}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{6}\NormalTok{,   }\CommentTok{#0.001, 1, 8, 1, 0.001, # Car dominated}
                \DecValTok{2}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{8}\NormalTok{,    }\DecValTok{4}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{6}\NormalTok{,   }\CommentTok{#0.001, 3, 5, 1, 1, # Elderly}
                \DecValTok{7}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{4}\NormalTok{,    }\DecValTok{3}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{8}\NormalTok{,   }\CommentTok{#1, 2, 5, 2, 1, # Female dominated}
                \DecValTok{5}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{4}\NormalTok{,    }\DecValTok{7}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{2}\NormalTok{,   }\CommentTok{#2, 1, 3, 1, 2, # Male dominated}
                \DecValTok{7}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{3}\NormalTok{,    }\DecValTok{6}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{4}    \CommentTok{#,   7, 0.001, 2, 0.001, 1  # Many cyclists, young}
                \NormalTok{)}
\NormalTok{all.msim <- }\KeywordTok{matrix}\NormalTok{(all.msim, }\DataTypeTok{nrow =} \DecValTok{5}\NormalTok{, }\DataTypeTok{byrow =} \NormalTok{T) }\CommentTok{# Convert long data into matrix, by row}
\NormalTok{all.msim <- }\KeywordTok{data.frame}\NormalTok{(all.msim) }\CommentTok{# Convert this into a dataframe}
\KeywordTok{names}\NormalTok{(all.msim) <- category.labels }\CommentTok{# Add correct column names}
\NormalTok{all.msim }\CommentTok{# Show the data frame in R}
\end{Highlighting}
```

)

Surely there's an easy way to remove this mess.

Comment: Don't use the `--standalone` flag if you don't want the preamble.

Comment: You can also use `--template` to specify a custom template with your own preamble.  See the pandoc documentation.

Comment: Hi Marco, that's fine but the output of the command without the tag still depends on a lengthy preamble. It produces a load of stuff that is unreadable to me, just for a simple table. E.g. \DecValTok{2}\NormalTok{, }\DecValTok{8}\NormalTok{,    }. So to develop one's own preamble that's compatible would not be that simple I reckon...

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the suggestion. Will take a look but was hoping for a quick and dirty solution to remove all the (in my view unnecessary) formatting. One possibility: perhaps my .md file is particularly awkward as it was generated by Rstudio's RMarkdown http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/r_markdown

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Pandoc and how it generates LaTeX output rather than a TeX issue.

Comment: This can really only be solved at the Pandoc end: that's not TeX's 'fault' so is off-topic (or at least on the border).

Comment: You might use `--listings` flag like `pandoc msim-eg.md -o msimeg.tex  --listings --standalone`